# Access Remote MySQL database from VM Instance

Tags: mysql, node.js, virtual-machine

I've been working with my Node App and deploy to VM Instance from Google Cloud. Now when I try to connect to RDS (Remote Database), it will flagged connect ETIMEOUT. One solution is to create a firewall rule which give access to database but still not working. May I ask if there's any alternative solution for this?

Not able to execute request.Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the cloud database you have to make sure of a few things:

- cloud database external ports are open
- cloud database is set to receive external connections
- you are using external ip, not internal ip
- mysql conf for the db allows external connections
- cloud database is online and ready to accept incoming connections
- your node environment can accept connections on the said ports

To debug the issue, I suggest you use either a command line client or a dedicated mysql client instead of the node app. That way you can test the cloud system without having your node system as a factor.

Comment: These are all check:
cloud database external ports are open
cloud database is set to receive external connections
you are using external ip, not internal ip
mysql conf for the db allows external connections
cloud database is online and ready to accept incoming connections

When I use localhost the connection is working well in terms of RDS connection.

Answer (score 0):

The Google cloud instance database could be accesed by external connections if you follow the steps in this page:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#configure-instance-mysql

Basically, you need to manage your database instance (https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances), and allow an external connection from a known IP (your computer public IP address) as **authorized network**.

Comment: does this apply also to Windows Server VM Instance? I tried to setup an SQL instance for this but the current tutorial is linux based.